# Route [] not defined in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, symfony, routes

I'm facing a weird situation:

I've a site which offers some downloads to registered users so I have this routes (among others)

```
| GET|HEAD  | productos/catalogos                       | product.catalog.index             | App\Http\Controllers\Front\CatalogController@index           
| GET|HEAD  | productos/catalogos/descargar/{slug}      | product.catalog.download          | App\Http\Controllers\Front\CatalogController@download        
| GET|HEAD  | productos/hojas-tecnicas                  | product.techsheet.index           | App\Http\Controllers\Front\TechnicalSheetsController@index   
| GET|HEAD  | productos/hojas-tecnicas/descargar/{slug} | product.techsheet.download        | App\Http\Controllers\Front\TechnicalSheetsController@download
```

Defined as that, routes for index are working perfectly, and catalog download is working too, but tech-sheet download fires the following error

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [] not defined.
```

I've tried with route helper and even with the full url eg: `http://domain.test/productos/hojas-tecnicas/descargar/1680268526-almacenamiento-y-manipulacion-de-cebadores-y-sondas-bhq` always with the same error.

So, if someone passed through something similar and could solve it, I will appreciate any idea.

Regards!

As required, here are the routes in web.php route file

```
Route::get('/productos/catalogos', '\App\Http\Controllers\Front\CatalogController@index')
    ->name('product.catalogs.index');
Route::get('/productos/catalogos/descargar/{slug}', '\App\Http\Controllers\Front\CatalogController@download')
    ->name('product.catalog.download');
Route::get('/productos/hojas-tecnicas', '\App\Http\Controllers\Front\TechnicalSheetsController@index')
    ->name('product.techsheets.index')
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
Route::get('/productos/hojas-tecnicas/descargar/{slug}', '\App\Http\Controllers\Front\TechnicalSheetsController@download')
    ->name('product.techsheets.download')
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

Both controllers and their functions exists and are working fine.

This is my download function in CatalogController, which is working perfectly fine.

```
    public function download(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        try {
            $catalog = Catalog::with('media')->published()->whereUuid($slug)->firstOrFail();
            $file = $catalog->hasMedia('pdf') ? $catalog->lastMedia('pdf')->getDiskPath() : null;
            $url = public_path().'/storage/'.$file;
            $name = basename($file);

            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'Binary',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment',
                'Expires' => 0,
                'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',

            ];

            return response()->download($url, $name, $headers, $disposition = 'attachment');

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Lo sentimos no se pudo localizar el archivo solicitado!');

            return redirect()->back();
        }    }
```

And this is my download function in TechnicalSheetsController which is firing the error

```
    public function download(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        try {
            $sheet = Post::with('media')->published()->whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
            $file = $sheet->hasMedia('pdf') ? $sheet->lastMedia('pdf')->getUrl() : null;
            $url = public_path().'/storage/'.$file;
            $name = basename($file);
            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'inline',
                'Expires' => 0,
                'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',
            ];

            return response()->download($file, $name, $headers);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Lo sentimos no se pudo localizar el archivo solicitado!');

            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the page listing downloadable files
[image: Inspector showing source code of the links which are triggering errors]

Comment: Can you provide more information? Such as controller method, route definitions?

Comment: Post your web.php or api.php file.

Comment: The output of `php artisan route:list` is helpful, but less so if you don't include `routes/web.php` (or `routes/api.php` if you're using that instead). You also might have an issue with a `route()` call. For example, `return redirect()->route($route)` will trigger that error if `$route` is `null` (or a simple `{{ route(null) }}`, in a `.blade.php` file, etc.). Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75988587/edit) to include your code, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: That's better; thank you for the updates  I don't see anything glaringly obvious, except for `->whereUuid($slug)` vs `->whereSlug($slug)`. I suspect that if you moved `$sheet = ...` _above_ the `try { }` block, your code would trigger a 404 instead of entering your `catch() { ... }` block.

Comment: I just realized that I was mixing routes with urls and that may be a part of the problem. I will fix that and report again.